# removing appended items

Tags: jquery

I have in my form a listbox.

```
<span>
    <select size=5 id="submission_author_ids" name="submission[author_ids][]"  multiple onfocus="displayOptions();"> </select>
  </span>
```

I have a function which reads all options in the listbox and then appends it in a div.

```
function displayOptions(){

var list = document.getElementById('submission_author_ids');
//$j('#spanSubmitters').remove();
for(var i = 0; i < list.options.length; ++i)
$j('#spanSubmitters').append(list.options[i].text);

 }
```

The problem is that each time focus is brought on the listbox, the options are appended to the div. This can results in duplication.
I would like to remove all appended options in the div first and append the options afresh each time the listbox receives focus.

I tried the code below but it's doesn't seem to be working --- options are no longer displayed

```
$j('#spanSubmitters').remove();
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me out with this.

Cheers

Comment: why remove and reappend, why not keep whats active in an array and not allow dupes?

Comment: because the listbox will be a hidden field..it is populated via a popup and i want to result (the options) to be displayed in a string format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/). `remove()` removes the whole element. `empty()` just removes all child nodes inside it.

```
$j('#spanSubmitters').empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$j('#spanSubmitters').children().remove();
```